# OpenCV - error when splitting channels

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use the remap function in OpenCV.
I have an STMap, so the `x` values are in the Red channel and `y` values are in the Green channel.

Here i'm loading my source image which i want to map, and the STMap:

```
Mat image3= imread("stmap.tif", CV_32FC1);
Mat image4= imread("source.tif", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

Then i split the channels to get the red and green ones from my STMap:

```
Mat bgr[3];   //destination array
split(image3,bgr);//split source

bgr[0].convertTo(bgr[0],CV_32FC1);
bgr[1].convertTo(bgr[1],CV_32FC1);
bgr[2].convertTo(bgr[2],CV_32FC1);
Mat dst;
```

And finally, the remapping part:

```
remap(image4, dst,bgr[2],bgr[1],INTER_LINEAR,BORDER_CONSTANT,Scalar(0,0,0));
```

However, when i display the `dst` Mat, it's all black.
I tried printing out some values to the console like:

```
cout << bgr[2].at<float>(1000,300);
```

but they're all 0's.
I displayed `bgr[1]` and `bgr[2]` and they're definitely not all black - they are greyscale gradients, like they should be.

So what could be the problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I noticed that whenever i would use a .jpeg file and the command:

```
cout << bgr2[2].at<float>(1000,300);
```

It would give me something like `0.1828510`

But when i run the same command with a 32bit .tif, it gives me:

```
1.04984e-320
```

**EDIT 2:**

How should i use the `convertMaps()` function?

This is what i tried and didn't work:

```
Mat image3= imread("STMap.jpg");
Mat image4= imread("image.jpg");

    Mat bgr[3];  
    split(image3,bgr);
    Mat map_x, map_y;
    map_x.create( image.size(), CV_32FC1 );
    map_y.create( image.size(), CV_32FC1 );    
    convertMaps(bgr[2], bgr[1], map_x, map_y, CV_32FC1);
```

Also, when i used `convertTo()`:

```
bgr[2].convertTo(red_channel, CV_32FC1, 1/255.0)
```

`bgr[2]` displayed correctly (the grayscale image of mapping intensities) and it the `red_channel` had all of its values between 0.0 and 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Your calls to `convertTo()` make no sense at all. Also have a look at the documentation of `remap()` and you will find reference to `convertMap()`, which is the method of choice for changing the matrix type (if you really have to!).

`remap()` expects the input to be in a certain range, probably also depending on the type of the input matrix. If it works with JPEGs but not with 32 bit TIFF I expect you have a data range issue.

Comment: Even without the call to `convertTo()` it gives the same result. So how would i use `remap()` to make it work with a 32bit .tif STMap and a corresponding 32bit .tif?

Comment: No wonder it doesn't work without `convertTo()`, as I said it makes no sense there and does nothing.

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense if my data type is of some sort and i'm trying to "clamp" it to 0.0-1.0 range so it would be of type `CV_32FC1` and therefore accepted by the `remap()` function?

Comment: `convertTo()` to a float does not clamp. And also why don't you go ahead and try `convertMap()` as I suggested?

Comment: Please see my edited post, and i'm not sure i understood how to use `convertMaps()`